# Нормировка выходных значений xgboost (на выходе регрессионной модели увеличенные значения)

Tags: python, linear-gradient, регрессия, xgboost

В данный момент разбираюсь с xgboost и столкнулся с проблемой. Обучил нейронную сеть xgboost на данных https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data?select=sample_submission.csv. Обучал разбивая обучающую выборку на тестовую и обучающую 0.2 к 0.8 соответственно. Так вот, на обучающей и тестовой выборке как всегда все нормально, а вот на проверочной, я получаю завышенные значения, хотя ни какие признаки не убирал, все обрабатывал вместе. К посту прикладываю график предсказанных и значений которые пытаемся предсказать. Как видно графики похожи, но имеют разный масштаб. Также прикладываю ссылку на github https://github.com/NikSuPNU/HousePricesPrediction.
Заранее спасибо!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разделенные значения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нормированные и разделенные значения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если не логарифмировать фичи, то сеть выдавала вот такие значения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После того, как была произведена нормировка двух датасетов с использованием одинаковых параметров. Но осталась та же проблема, как будто появляется модулирующая частотная помеха.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну тут же и завышенные и заниженные. А проверочная точно проходит те же обработки, что трейн и тест? И если используются скейлеры для фич, то их параметры те же, что на трейне/тесте?

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, вся предобработка происходит однотипно. В самом начале я конкатинирую два датафрейма, произвожу очистку и заполнение пропущенных значений, после чего разделяю.

Comment: А на нижней оси у вас что, кстати? Если просто номер наблюдения, то я бы попробовал нарисовать в отсортированном виде, например по реальным значениям, или по предсказанным. Сейчас не очень понятно что происходит.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да оси Х у меня номер наблюдения, по оси Y значения log(предсказанные) или log(реальные). К вопросу добавил рисунок с подписями.

Comment: И всё-таки покажите ваш пайплайн. И как вы делаете нормировку

Comment: А главное - зачем вы её делаете? Логарифмирование таргета нужно, тут я согласен. И потом обратно экспонента после предсказания. А нормализация фич для сложных моделей не нужна. Возможно, вы делаете нормализацию отдельно для каждой части данных? Тогда у вас могут быть проблемы, если матожидание и/или стандартное отклонение для проверочной части отличается. Нужно запоминать параметры скейлинга трейна и применять их на тесте и отложенной выборке. Если этого не делать, то где-то проблем не будет, а где-то будут

Comment: А, ну похоже как я и думал. Вы там выкидываете выбросы, используя интерквантильные расстояния отдельно для отложенной выборки. Так делать нельзя, выбросы нужно выкидывать синхронно из всех частей выборки. Хотя может и не в этом дело. Но принцип такой, что все выборки должны обрабатываться с использованием параметров тренировочной выборки.

Comment: @CrazyElf Хорошо, я реализовал ваше предложение. Ситуация идентична. Обновления добавил на гитхаб.

Comment: @CrazyElf Реализовал все, что вы сказали, также добавил проверку последовательности столбцов, использовал компоненты для фильтрации одинаковые. Но появляется все та же несущая...